# Assigning local CRS to space telescope imagery?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, local-scene

Since the new images became available from the James Webb space telescope (https://webbtelescope.org/resource-gallery/images), I want to test some of my favorite classification, segmentation, and object detection methods on them but (for obvious reasons) the images do not have any projection or datum attached.

I've seen some posts that say you can just arbitrarily assign a projected CRS to the images but would like to know if there are any best practices for doing this in a systematic way. I'm open to any solutions in QGIS/grass, python, or R.

Comment: Please decide which particular GIS software you wish to ask about in this particular question. Asking for best practices will usually attract close votes for seeking opinions.